# Current URL PHP / CURL

Tags: php, curl

- I have http://www.domain_1.com/index.php. In this file I have a variable called `$url = 'http://www.mydomain2.com/mypage.php';`
- In http://www.mydomain2.com/mypage.php I call the first file via CURL.
- How do I check in index.php if the file was called from the specified URL?

FILE 1 (on domain1):

```
<?php $url='http://www.domain2.php'; ?>
```

FILE 2 (on domain2)

```
<?php 
$connect_to = 'http://domain1/index.php';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $connect_to);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Now, on file 1, I want to check if the curl call was made from the specified url, otherwise return an error.

Comment: What the heck? Please, post you snippet code here to see what you have tried...

Comment: I don't have a code snippet. Is just <php $url='http://www.mydomain2.com/mypage.php'; ?> My question is how do I check if this page containing this variable is called via CURL from the specified address.

Comment: Are you looking for the Referrer?

Comment: nope, I am looking for URL that is making the CURL call and it should match the url in the variable.

Comment: you could restrict using htaccess or something similar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the IP that sends the request to your first script and compare it to the IP of your second script:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == gethostbyname('www.mydomain2.com')) {
// Do whatever you need.
}
```

NOTICE: This will only tell you if the IP of the machine that does the request matches the IP of the second domain.
If you have two scripts on your second domain that do CURL requests to your first domain you would not be able to recognize which one does the request.